# How to get data from dialog activity when it is finished

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity which calls another activity with dialog theme. There are some buttons. User press one of the buttons and this activity destoys - then main activity gets the focus. In the onResume() method of main activity i can find out that the dialog activity is closed. But how can i receive data from this dialog activity - define which button was pressed?

Comment: check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android

Comment: are you navigating to one activity to another ?

Comment: KuLdip PaTel, thanks a lot! I allways thought that onActivityResult is called only after recreation of activity. Now i understand that it can be also called even when activity resumes!